# PerfMon web interface - does it exist?

Tags: monitoring, perfmon, performance

I realise that it is fairly easy to query performance counters in code and display these on an ASPX page but does anyone know if a product already exists which is basically a web version of PerfMon - free or otherwise?

many thanks

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

[HP SiteScope](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-15-25%5E849_4000_100__) can do this.